# WCF Rest Post from Backbone.js always receives null object on server

Tags: json, wcf, rest, backbone.js

I am using backbone.js and posting the model ( todo ) to the wcf Rest service whose details you can find below. For some reason the implementation always receives a null value regardless of the posted json.

#### Contract

```
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Todos", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    [OperationContract]
    Wallet CreateTodos(Todo instance);
```

#### Implementation

```
    public Wallet CreateTodos(Todo instance)
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable;
            return null;
        }

      ... blah blah blah
```

#### Data Contract

```
[DataContract]
Public Class Todo
{    
  [DataMember]
  public string Name{get;set;}    
}
```

#### Post Json

{
  "Name":"Welcome Guests"
}

#### Http Details

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:281
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost/todos/index.html
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: Can you monitor on how you raw request looks like and post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your raw request should looks something like below:

```
POST http://localhost:54897/Sample.svc/Todos HTTP 1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost

{"instance":{"Name":"This is my first todo"}
```

Comment: But how come Update works
`[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Wallets/{id}", Method = "PUT")]
[OperationContract]
Todo UpdateTodo(string id, Todo instance);`
Which does a post to `localhost/Sample.svc/Todos/1` with `{"Name":"Welcome"}` how come that transformed correctly

Comment: You have your bodystyle set to wrappedrequest on your post method

Comment: So what would be right configuration to make it work similar to `PUT` request other than changing Method to `PUT`

Comment: btw the http post and other look same as in http://www.servicestack.net/Backbone.Todos/ ( but i am just using Wcf here)

Comment: Removing the BodyStyle attribute on your POST method should make it similar to PUT